# Pass a parameter into ssrs url

Tags: url, reporting-services

i have a report on my Report Server. How i can access from some application to my report, named Report1.rdl with parameters and to export to some format, for example CSV.

So far i have this

[http://server/ReportServer?%2fIntegration%2fReport1&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=CSV](http://server/ReportServer?%2FIntegration%2FReport1&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=CSV)

How to put parameters `ReportDate_FromDate,ReportDate_ToDate` into my URL and when i access from some application to see file exported in CSV

Answer (score 0):

Copy the url then add &[ParameterName]=[value] to the end like

```
http://server/ReportServer?%2fIntegration%2fReport1&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=CSV&ReportDate_FromDate='01-Jan-2016'&ReportDate_ToDate='13-Apr-2016'
```

Comment: This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'ReportDate_FromDate'. When i put default value for Date is ok, but i never takes my value from the URL